# Binding html string content to Webview in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, webview

I have a webview in my xaml which looks as follows :

```
<WebView x:Name="WebView" />
```

And, in my codebehind I have a variable called "htmlcontent", which contains html string data which looks like as follows :

```
<html><body><b>Hi there</b></body></html>
```

How can I bind this html string and display it formatted in the webview component of the XAML?

*Edit - By the way, I am doing a Windows 8 metro application, so the WebBrowser control isn't supported

Comment: [Binding HTML to a WebView with Attached Properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/09/26/binding-html-to-a-webview-with-attached-properties.aspx)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The HtmlString property does not exist on WebView (only the Source property which is an Uri). But what you can do is to define yourself a new HtmlString attached property for WebView. Just create the following class :

```
namespace YOURNAMESPACE
{
    class MyProperties
    {
     // "HtmlString" attached property for a WebView
     public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HtmlString", typeof(string), typeof(MyProperties), new PropertyMetadata("", OnHtmlStringChanged));

     // Getter and Setter
     public static string GetHtmlString(DependencyObject obj) { return (string)obj.GetValue(HtmlStringProperty); }
     public static void SetHtmlString(DependencyObject obj, string value) { obj.SetValue(HtmlStringProperty, value); }

     // Handler for property changes in the DataContext : set the WebView
     private static void OnHtmlStringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
     {
        WebView wv = d as WebView; 
        if (wv != null) 
        { 
            wv.NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue); 
        } 
     }
    }
}
```

Supposing that your DataContext field is called CurrentHtmlString, then you can use this new WebView's HtmlString property in your XAML file to bind it, with a syntax like :

```
 <WebView local:MyProperties.HtmlString="{Binding CurrentHtmlString}"></WebView>
```

Normally you already have the following line at the top of your XAML file :

```
xmlns:local="using:MYNAMESPACE"
```

You can find more explanation here from Rob Caplan : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/09/26/binding-html-to-a-webview-with-attached-properties.aspx