# My piece of HTML won't display in my WebView in C#/XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, webview, rss

My application reads a RSS feed and display it in a list.  This mostly works:

```
var rssfeed = new RSSfeed();    // make instance to use
string s = await rssfeed.GetHttpStr(feedUrl);   // get feed as string
this.items = rssfeed.ParseRSS(s); // parse RSS into a list
```

(RSSfeed is a model of an item in the feed. s is the http response string.  ParseRSS is a method that converts the string, using the model, into an object.)

(To made this brief, I've excluded the code behind the methods.  If you want I can post has as well on request.)

The following loop will place each item into the ListView.

```
        foreach (var item in myItems)
        {
            var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = @"<html><body>" + item.Desc + "</body></html>"
            };
            this.items.Add(new RSSItem
            {
                Title = item.Title,
                Link = item.Link,
                ID = item.Id,
                Desc = htmlSource.Html
            });
        }
```

Here is my XAML, inside my DataTemplate:

```
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame OutlineColor="Gray">
                    <StackLayout Margin="5" Padding="5">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="SteelBlue" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Link}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Green" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Desc}" TextColor="Fuchsia" />
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <WebView Source="{Binding Desc}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
```

(Apparently the WebView wrapped in a Grid doesn't require a Width/HeightRequest - is this true?  Is there another way to make it dynamically sized to the contents?)

The ListView shows fine (and most RSS fields) but my WebView is empty.  What do I need to display the "Desc" (a simple HTML image tag) in the WebView?

Answer (score 0):

`WebView.Source` is a `Uri` not a `string`. If you want to view custom HTML content, you'll need to use the `NavigateToString(html)` method. Unfortunately, you can't bind to that either, but there's a [workaround found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505461/binding-html-string-content-to-webview-in-xaml).

Comment: I already read this post. I'll try it again. Have you used it? Do you know how to make the contents dynamic fit?

Comment: It might work, do you know how to rid the errors: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'DependencyProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  AND  Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'DependencyObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) , etc.?

Comment: That link you gave is over 3 years old.  Things change very fast in the IT world.  Can you confirm it works?

Comment: Yes I use it. I play with WebViews all the time and if you want to display your own HTML, you have to either create a temporary file with your content and point the source URL to it, or use `NavigateToString()`. If you find an alternate solution, please post it here.