# Display database to listbox

Tags: c#, database, uwp, listbox

I have a listbox containing a choice of text answers taken from the database and containing html languages, such as: <p>, etc. I want to display it so that the html language is not displayed. I tried to display it in the webview, but <p>, etc. is still visible.
XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="ListOption" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,20,10,0" Height="auto" xmlns:m="using:KipinSchool_Win10.TryoutData.Models" SelectionChanged="ListAlternatives_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:DBOption">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <WebView Margin="10,10,10,10" local:MyProperties.HtmlString="{Binding Option}" MinHeight="40" MaxHeight="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Tag="{Binding OID}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Option}" Tag="{Binding OID}" FontSize="19"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Code:

```
string strA = @"SELECT DISTINCT* FROM DBOption WHERE QID='" + question[0] + "'";
            var alternative = objConn.Prepare(strA);

            ObservableCollection<DBOption> Items = new ObservableCollection<DBOption>();

            int i = 0;
            while (alternative.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
            {
                Items.Add(new DBOption(alternative[0].ToString(), alternative[1].ToString(), alternative[2].ToString(), alternative[3].ToString()));
            }
            Binding myBinding = new Binding();
            myBinding.Source = Items;
            ListOption.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

How to handle it?

Comment: Does it mean that you want to render rich text in the list box ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari yes

Comment: @Rose, could share a html string sample ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT for example: <p>2 x 15 menit</p>

Comment: Have you check this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28510331/7254781).

Comment: The problem is that the webview is located in the listbox

Comment: If the bind `HtmlString` is correct, WebView will display html string, I checked your xaml, it looks correctly.

Comment: but the <p> is still display in webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to display it in the webview, but  etc.  is still visible. XAML:

I could reproduce your issue, the problem is that you have not set width and height property for WebView. And html string does not contain the content height. So the `WebView` will not display correctly. Please modify the code like the following.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <WebView Margin="10,10,10,10" 
                     local:MyProperties.HtmlString="{Binding Option}"    
                     Height="400" Width="200"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     Tag="{Binding OID}"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I have set Minheight and Maxheight and also Horizontal Alignment = "stretch"

Comment: But webview will not display render with `Minheight`  `Maxheight` property. Please try to set height and width property.

Comment: I have added height, but <p>, etc. is still on the webview

Comment: @Rose please check this code [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/WebViewInListBox).